# Complex derivative of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I've got the following question. We have a function $f(x,y) :R^2 \rightarrow R^2$ and we treat R^2 as complex numbers. We know that $\frac{df}{dy} = z_1$. Knowing that $f$ has a complex derivative, compute $\frac{df}{dx}$. Can somebody explain it to me? What exactly should I do? Do I have enough data to compute it? In which terms should the answer be? I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just started studying complex math myself. Here is my attempt to solve the puzzle. Hopefully an expert will review my answer.

---

If $f$ has a derivative, it must satisfy the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations).  If you write $f$ as $f(x,y) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$, where $u$ and $v$ are real, the Cauchy-Riemann equations say:

$$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial{v}}{\partial y}$$
$$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial y} = - \frac{\partial{v}}{\partial x}$$

Now if you write out the derivative:

$$\frac{df}{d x} = \frac{d}{dx}(u(x,y) + iv(x,y)) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

Thanks to Cauchy-Riemann, this must be equal to:

$$= \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} - i \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$
But it is given that:

$$\frac{df}{dy} = z_1 = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + i \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$

So:

$$\frac{df}{dx} = Im(z_1) - i Re(z_1) = - i z_1$$

Comment: It may be beneficial to observe that $\operatorname{Im}(z_1) - i \operatorname{Re}(z_1) = -i\cdot z_1$.